# Why won't make let me build my kernel from source?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, make

```
$ make menuconfig
```

> Makefile:128: *** main directory cannot contain spaces nor colons.  Stop.

I get this error message. Why?

Answer (score 6):

That message means that the current directory (containing the Makefile) has a full path which contains at least one space or colon, and that’s not supported. You need to move your source tree elsewhere.